# Laptop brightness automatically decreases to zero but if I press refresh, backspace, enter or spacebar keys it stops decreasing

Tags: laptop, keyboard, display, lenovo-laptop, brightness

I have turned off automatic display brightness and I don't think it is a display hardware issue as when I started the BIOS i didn't have any changes in brightness. I got an old Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 windows 8 i5-3337U and 4gb ram working after maybe a year of non-usage. The battery is fine it works after unplugging the charger also. Now that those details are out of the way here is the problem.

Now the problem is that as soon as I start the laptop the brightness just decreases in steps all the way to zero. If i try to increase the brightness by pressing the button it decreases again at the same rate so I have to hold the brightness up button for it to be maximum then if I press backspace, refresh, enter or spacebar keys it stops decreasing and everything is normal. After that if i press any of the number keys or brightness decrease key (f11) it again starts to decrease. Please suggest a solution I'm at the end of my wits here.

Comment: Update BIOS, and Power Driver (update or reinstall).  Set brightness settings to default (Settings, Display). Do a final restart and test.

Comment: All done but no luck :(

Comment: You said this was an old machine you got. Try reinstalling Windows as a fresh install and see if that works.

Comment: Look for an application running in the background causing this, or a stuck key (e.g., the F-key for brightness. Workaround: in BIOS, switch function keys for hardware control (brightness, volume, etc.) to require that the Fn key be depressed.